# Iterative Imputor gives the same output for all the values it has to impute

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, data-imputation

I have a `df` named `so` as follows:

```
      gas day    RLM       Date
0   22.03.2020  5501593 2020-03-22
1   23.03.2020  9232167 2020-03-23
2   24.03.2020  8807847 2020-03-24
3   25.03.2020  8561604 2020-03-25
4   26.03.2020  7775652 2020-03-26
5   27.03.2020  56022577 2020-03-27
6   28.03.2020  4556959 2020-03-28
7   29.03.2020  5233497 2020-03-29
8   30.03.2020  8181341 2020-03-30
9   31.03.2020  8063470 2020-03-31
```

The user can select a few values from the `RLM` column and those values have to be replaced with a `NaN` and interpolated using [sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html#sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer). For that I am doing:

```
def bayseian_interpolate(data: pd.DataFrame,
                         to_replace: list,
                         measure: str = 'RLM'):
    data_interpolation = data.copy()
    data_interpolation[measure] = data_interpolation[measure].replace(
        to_replace, np.nan)
    s = data_interpolation[measure].isna()
    imp = IterativeImputer(random_state=0)
    imp.fit(data_interpolation[measure].values.reshape(-1, 1))
    X = data_interpolation[measure].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    data_interpolation[measure] = imp.transform(X)
    for orig, imputed in zip(data.loc[s, measure], data_interpolation.loc[s, measure]):
        st.write('The value {} is interpolated as {}'.format(
            orig, round(imputed, 2)))
```

Followed by

```
values_to_interpolate = [56022577, 8181341]
bayseian_interpolate(so, values_to_interpolate)
```

The imputation gives the same value for all the `values_to_interpolate`. Is there a mistake that I am doing?

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? Also, 'RLM' is a column of integers?

Comment: @Ale The scikit-learn version is 0.22.2.post1. and it is of integers, but can also contain float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `imp.fit(data_interpolation[measure].values.reshape(-1, 1))` which should take as input the whole dataframe.

I tried to use as input the whole dataframe `imp.fit(data_interpolation)` but in your example it raises the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '22.03.2020'`.

However, with a syntetic dataframe

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['gas day','RLM','Date'])
df


    gas day     RLM         Date
0   0.548814    0.715189    0.602763
1   0.544883    0.423655    0.645894
2   0.437587    0.891773    0.963663
3   0.383442    0.791725    0.528895
4   0.568045    0.925597    0.071036
5   0.087129    0.020218    0.832620
6   0.778157    0.870012    0.978618
7   0.799159    0.461479    0.780529
8   0.118274    0.639921    0.143353
9   0.944669    0.521848    0.414662
```

Adapting your function to:

```
def bayseian_interpolate_2(data: pd.DataFrame,
                         to_replace: list,
                         measure: str = 'RLM'):
    data_interpolation = data.copy()
    data_interpolation[measure] = data_interpolation[measure].replace(
        to_replace, np.nan)
    s = data_interpolation[measure].isna()
    imp = IterativeImputer(random_state=0)
#     imp.fit(data_interpolation[measure].values.reshape(-1, 1))
    imp.fit(data_interpolation)
#     X = data_interpolation[measure].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    X = data_interpolation
    data_interpolation[measure] = imp.transform(X)
    for orig, imputed in zip(data.loc[s, measure], data_interpolation.loc[s, measure]):
        print('The value {} is interpolated as {}'.format(
            orig, round(imputed, 2)))
```

Leads to the expected outcome:

```
values_to_interpolate = [df['RLM'][5], df['RLM'][8]]
bayseian_interpolate_2(df, values_to_interpolate)

The value 0.02021839744032572 is interpolated as 0.09
The value 0.6399210213275238 is interpolated as 0.12
```

As a counterexample, if I use your original function on my syntethic dataframe I also get the same value:

```
The value 0.02021839744032572 is interpolated as 0.7
The value 0.6399210213275238 is interpolated as 0.7
```